# MVVM Binding: create new object in view object

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

Normally i would create all objects in the view and bind its properties to the viewmodel/model. But what if a control has a property of another type, not string/bool?

For example a simple chart which can have a legend of the type "Chart.Legend"

The view:

```
<ChartControl x:Name="{Binding ChartModelObject.Name}" Data="{Binding ChartModelObject.Data}">
    <ChartControl.Legend Postiton="{Binding ChartModelObject.Legend.Position}">
        <ChartControlLegend/>
    </ChartControl.Legend">
</ChartControl>
```

with the ViewModel

```
public class ChartViewModel
{
    public ChartModel ChartModelObject{ get; set; }
}
```

and the Model

```
public class ChartModel
{
    public LegendModel Legend { get; set; }
    public String Name { get; set; }
    public IData Data { get; set; }
}
public class LegendModel 
{
    public PositionEnum Position { get; set; }
}
```

Depending if my ChartModels property "Legend" has an instance of type LegendModel and is not null, i would like to show the legend, otherwise not. Now i've to create an object of type "ChartControl.Legend" in the view or another way would bind ChartControl.Legend directly to the ChartModel.LegendModel. But how do i achieve this?

**EDIT:**

a more general example

the **View**

```
<Button Content="{Binding Name}" FontSize="14" FontWeight="Bold">
  <!-- Only use a LinearGradientBrush if there is a ExampleModelObject Object-->
  <Button.Background>
    <LinearGradientBrush StartPoint="0,0.5" 
                            EndPoint="1,0.5">
      <GradientStop Color="Green" Offset="{Binding ExampleModelObject.FirstPoint}" />
      <GradientStop Color="White" Offset="{Binding ExampleModelObject.SecondPoint}" />
    </LinearGradientBrush>

  </Button.Background>
</Button>
```

the **ViewModel**

```
public class ExampleViewModel
{
    public ButtonBackgroundExampleModel ExampleModelObject{ get; set; }
    public string Name {get;set}
}
```

the **Model**

```
public class ButtonBackgroundExampleModel
{
    public double FirstPoint { get; set; }
    public double SecondPoint { get; set; }
}
```

Depending if the ViewModel has an instance of the ButtonBackgroundExampleModel, i would like to create a Button.Background.LinearGradientBrush. If there is no ButtonBackgroundExampleModel (no FirstPoint,SecondPoint) there should be no Button.Background. So, it should be:

```
<Button Content="{Binding Name}" FontSize="14" FontWeight="Bold">
</Button>
```

Comment: "if my ChartModels property "Legend" has an instance of type LegendModel and is not null, i would like to show the legend, otherwise not" - sounds like a DataTrigger

Comment: @Alexander: You are supposed to create the `ChartModel` in the view model. The (default) template in the view should take care of not showing the legend if there is none.

Comment: @mm8 but how do i take care that ChartControl.Legend (in the view) is not created or shown? Do i have to make it in the code behind or how do i handle that in xaml?

Comment: @Alexander: Please clarify what `ChartControl` you are using, what you want to do and what you have tried by posting a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: @mm8  added a more general example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a `Style` with a `DataTrigger` to determine whether the `ExampleModelObject` property is set:

```
<Button Content="{Binding Name}" FontSize="14" FontWeight="Bold">
    <!-- Only use a LinearGradientBrush if there is a ExampleModelObject Object-->
    <Button.Style>
        <Style TargetType="Button" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type Button}}">
            <Setter Property="Background">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <LinearGradientBrush StartPoint="0,0.5" EndPoint="1,0.5">
                        <GradientStop Color="Green" Offset="{Binding ExampleModelObject.FirstPoint}" />
                        <GradientStop Color="White" Offset="{Binding ExampleModelObject.SecondPoint}" />
                    </LinearGradientBrush>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ExampleModelObject}" Value="{x:Null}">
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="#FFDDDDDD" />
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </Button.Style>
</Button>
```